# Reduce array of empty arrays

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to run a reduce function on an array on arrays. The arrays inside the array can be empty. So:
[[], [], [], []].reduce((x, y) => x.length + y.length) does not work

[[2, 3], [2, 3], [3, 5], [5, 6]].reduce((x, y) => x.length + y.length) doesn't seem to work either?

Am I missing something?

Comment: `[[], [], [], []].reduce((x, y) => x.length + y.length) ` is not working because you are returning an integer value and not an array. So in second iteration, it will fail as number does not have `.length`

Comment: please add the potential result of the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature for the function you pass as the first argument to `.reduce` is

```
(accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {...}
```

The second argument you can pass to `reduce` is the starting value for the accumulator.

In your case, `(x, y) => x.length + y.length` is trying to get the `length` of the accumulator, named `x`, which will be `undefined`, and add it to the `length` of the first array in the parent array.

When you try to add `undefined` to a number, you get `NaN`.

My guess is that you're trying to calculate the aggregate length of all the arrays in your parent array? If so, try this...

```
[[],[],[],[]].reduce((acc, array) => acc + array.length, 0)
// returns 0

[[2, 3], [2, 3], [3, 5], [5, 6]].reduce((acc, array) => acc + array.length, 0)
// returns 8
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, it just looks like you missed the callback structure for reduce. For future reference the MDN page for the `.reduce` is [pretty comprehensive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=b)

Comment: ohhhh I see. so 'array' in this case is the element for the current iteration?

Comment: Yes - exactly. `reduce` is a bit of a weird one as the first argument to the callback is the accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a start value for [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
var getLength = (r, x) => r + x.length,
    length0 = [[], [], [], []].reduce(getLength, 0),
    //                                           ^
    length1 = [[2, 3], [2, 3], [3, 5], [5, 6]].reduce(getLength, 0);
    //                                                           ^

console.log(length0);
console.log(length1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch out because x.length and y.length will eventually turn into integers and integers don't have a length property.

You can do something like

```
(x, y) => x.length || x + y.length || y
```

So that if x.length exists, it gets used, otherwise just use the value of x